# Understanding Steps Involved in Complex Analysis Proof

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation

I am trying to figure out the ("arithmetical") steps that were taken to get from:

$\frac{f(u,t)}{(t-v)(t-v-h)}$

to

$\frac{f(u,t)}{(t-v)^2} + \frac{hf(u,t)}{(t-v-h)(t-v)^2}$

This calculation was sneaked in to simplify an integral as part of a proof I am currently reading for Complex Analysis (and once I figure it out I complete my understanding of said proof). This is in no way a homework related question, I am merely trying to understand how to get from "point A" to point B". Any pointing in the right direction is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try working backwards and just simplifying the second expression?

Comment: I just did as just suggested, and can see where I got 'tripped up'. I also see the question was just answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{1}{A(A-B)}=\frac{A}{A^2(A-B)}
=\frac{(A-B)+B}{A^2(A-B)}=
\frac{1}{A^2}+\frac{B}{A^2(A-B)}
$$
Now use $A=t-v$ and $B=h$.